# Link href not working Page not found error in Next js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

so I'm working on a login system in next.js, and in the login page, I've added a Link to the Register page through Link href, but whenever I click on that link, it says 404 page not found. All the files are in the same folder, and I've tried to copy-paste everything into another next js project just to check if there's some configuration error. Still no use. Can anyone explain this?

```js
<p className="mt-10 text-center text-sm text-gray-500">
    Not a member?
    <Link
       href="./Register.js"
       className="font-semibold leading-6 text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"
     >
       Register now
     </Link>
  </p>
```

Upon clicking on the Link attribute, it should be redirected to Register.js, but instead, it shows 404 pages not found.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77526186/how-do-you-fix-next-js-14-next-link-routing-404-error-page-issue/77526445#77526445)). The solution for me was to create a separate folder for each page.tsx (or page.js in your case). So if you want to make a link to Register.js, you would have to make a folder inside /app/register and then put a file called page.js inside that new folder. Your link would be href="/register".

Official documentation here [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#pages).

Comment: My bad, I may have commented on this answer by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the `/register` route by a Component route in the AppRouter (I assumed your NextJs is 13.xx), and then in the `href` prop of the `Link` component, use the route names. Like the following:

```js
<Link
  href="/register"
  className="font-semibold leading-6 text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
  Register now
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create or make sure you've already created a `Register.js` file in your `pages/` directory. Once you've ensured that this has been created. You would then need to make sure that you're importing Link from the correct Location. Here is a code snippet that should help.

```js
import Link from 'next/link'
 
function Component() {
  return (
    <p className="mt-10 text-center text-sm text-gray-500">
        Not a member?
        <Link
            to="/register"
            className="font-semibold leading-6 text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"
        >
           Register now
        </Link>
    </p>
  )
}
 
export default Component;
```